# Jupiter V6 Swap API. Problem with commission

Tags: javascript

**Jupiter Swap V6 Problem with commission.**

Hello, I have a problem. I made a node js script to send a swap through the jupiter ag platform.

My transaction is successful, but the solscan page displays No Data and there is no transaction, it does not go through.

As I understand it, the error is that in my transaction the commission is minimal and therefore the transaction does not go through.
Out of 50 transactions, only 1-2 are successful for me.
I have a referral API key but I don’t understand how to install it to make a commission.

Please help me how can I set a commission for a transaction, I looked at the documentation but I still don’t understand how to set it correctly in order to set a commission for a transaction.

https://station.jup.ag/docs/apis/adding-fees

https://station.jup.ag/docs/apis/swap-api#6-get-the-serialized-transactions-to-perform-the-swap

Here is an example transaction:
https://solscan.io/tx/gz8wng1SqCgkaYZsZBMzt5GwZESZ41DQHuycTLENCKmj5empCLyVoJoPvwzvcbVkNRB5MKZQHVaa8eNk8eCz3Ww
[image: Solscan]

Here is my code that I use to make a swap:

```
import { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey, VersionedTransaction } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { createJupiterApiClient } from '@jup-ag/api';
import { Wallet } from '@project-serum/anchor';
import axios from 'axios';
import bs58 from 'bs58';
import logger from './logger.js';
import { cfgSwap, cfgScript, cfgDeal } from './config.js';

const jupiterQuoteApi = createJupiterApiClient();
const wallet = new Wallet(Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(cfgSwap.PRIVATE_KEY || '')));
const connection = new Connection(cfgScript.RPC_ENDPOINT, { wsEndpoint: cfgScript.RPC_WEBSOCKET });
const feeAccount = "FTECPy8Qt1JtJwvE7p3qPuvVLWB";


async function swap(input_mint, output_mint, amount) {
    const new_amount = amount * cfgDeal.SOL_DIVIDE;
    const slippagebps = cfgDeal.MAX_SLIPPAGE_TOLERANCE;
    const extrafee = cfgDeal.EXTRA_FEE;

    const quote = await jupiterQuoteApi.quoteGet({
        inputMint: input_mint,
        outputMint: output_mint,
        amount: new_amount,
        slippageBps: slippagebps,
        swapMode: 'ExactOut',
        onlyDirectRoutes: false,
        asLegacyTransaction: false,
    });

    const swapTransaction = await jupiterQuoteApi.swapPost({
        swapRequest: {
            quoteResponse: quote,
            userPublicKey: wallet.publicKey.toBase58(),
            dynamicComputeUnitLimit: true,
            wrapAndUnwrapSol: true,
            prioritizationFeeLamports: 'auto',
            preflightCommitment: 'processed',
            
            },
        });
    
        logger.info('[post_swap] Attempting to send a request.');
        const swapTransactionBuffer = Buffer.from(swapTransaction.swapTransaction, "base64");
        const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(swapTransactionBuffer);
        transaction.sign([wallet.payer])
    
        var tryAgain = true;
        var objSignatureStatusResult;
        var maxTriesCounter = 0;
        var maxTries = 5;
        logger.info('[transaction] Attempting to create a transaction');
        
        while (tryAgain) {
            maxTriesCounter++;
            const rawTransaction = transaction.serialize();
            const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(rawTransaction, {
            skipPreflight: true,
            maxRetries: 5,
            preflightCommitment: 'confirmed',
            });
    
            logger.info(`Swap successful! Transaction ID: ${txid}`);
            logger.info(`View the transaction Sosclan: https://solscan.io/tx/${txid}`);
    
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1500));
    
            const result = await connection.getSignatureStatus(txid, {
            searchTransactionHistory: true,
            });
            objSignatureStatusResult = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
            if (objSignatureStatusResult.value !== null) tryAgain = false;
            if (maxTriesCounter>maxTries) tryAgain = false;
            return txid;
        }
}



async function swapRun() {
    await swap(
        "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
        "JUPyiwrYJFskUPiHa7hkeR8VUtAeFoSYbKedZNsDvCN",
        0.001
    );
}

swapRun();
```